# Help with a reduction of order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

$x^2y''-2xy'+(x^2+2)y=0, x>0, y_1(x)=xsinx$

I found

$y_2(x)=u(x)xsinx$

$y_2' =u'xsinx+usinx+uxcosx$

$y_2''=u''xsinx+2u'sinx+2u'xcosx+2ucosx-uxsinx$ (collected terms)

But when I substitute these back into the original differential equation, I get a REALLY messy answer. Have any idea if I did something incorrectly? I appreciate any help/walkthrough of this problem!

Comment: Looks right so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help to rewrite things as

$$y_2''=u''x\sin x+u'(2\sin x+2x\cos x)+u(2\cos x-x\sin x)$$
$$y_2'=u'x\sin x+u(\sin x+x\cos x)$$
$$x^2y_2''-2xy_2'+(x^2+2)y_2=u''x^3\sin x+u'(2x^2\sin x+2x^3\cos x-2x^2\sin x)+$$
$$u(2x^2\cos x-x^3\sin x-2x\sin x-2x^2\cos x+x^3\sin x+2x\sin x)=0$$

The $u$ term cancels out as it should since $kx\sin x$ is supposed to be a solution.  All you are left with is

$$u''x^3\sin x+2u'x^3\cos x=0$$
$$u''+\frac{2\cos x}{\sin x}u'=0$$
Integrating factor should be relatively easy.

$$u''\sin^2x+2u'\sin x\cos x=0$$
$$u'\sin^2x=a,u'=a\csc^2x$$
$$u=a_2\cot x+k$$

So the complete solution should be
$$y=(a_2\cot x+k)x\sin x=a_2x\cos x+kx\sin x$$

Comment: Thanks! That was pretty helpful! I get it now.